# Redirect https non-www to https www url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

How can i redirect an https non-www to https www url?
Sample is `https://example.com/page` to `https://www.example.com/page`

I have this redirect code in my ".htaccess" file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works for `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` however it doesn't seem to work for `https://example.com/page` to `https://www.example.com/page`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The rule you’ve posted is correct, however, you’ve probably put it in the wrong place. This rule needs to go at the top of the htaccess file, not at the end. (Aside: How are you redirecting HTTP + www?)

Comment: Also make sure that you are not looking at a client side cached result that got generated prior to you implementing this redirection rule.